# How to get properties out of Microsoft XML CoXMLHTTP60 response in Delphi 6?

Tags: json, delphi, com, xmlhttprequest, delphi-6

I'm trying to connect to a REST web service using Delphi 6. I've been able to successfully do this with the code below:

```
function WSConnect(url: WideString; params: TStringList = nil; method: WideString = 'GET'):WideString;
var
    request: XMLHTTP60;
begin
    // CreateQueryString below just adds any params passed in to the end of the url
    url := url + CreateQueryString(params); 

    CoInitialize(nil);
    request := CoXMLHTTP60.Create;
    request.open(method,url,false,'','');

    request.send('');

    if request.status=200 then
    begin
        Result := request.responseText;
    end else
        Result := 'Error: (' + inttostr(request.Status) + ') ' + request.StatusText;
    
    CoUninitialize();
end;
```

I've pieced together this code from different examples around the net, but I can't find any documentation on CoXMLHTTP60. The code works great, but the current implementation only gives me back a string with the JSON response in it, and I'm struggling to figure out how to pull the properties out of this JSON string in Delphi 6. I've looked at [SuperObjects](https://github.com/hgourvest/superobject) (which people say has problems with Delphi 6 so I didn't try it) and a different project called [json4delphi](https://github.com/rilyu/json4delphi) that I couldn't get to compile in Delphi 6 despite it saying it is compatible.

There are also different properties on the CoXMLHTTP60 response object that I believe might get me the values I need. They are:

```
request.responseBody: OleVariant;
request.responseStream: OleVariant;
request.responseXML: IDispatch;
```

I would think one of these would provide access to the properties in the JSON, but I can't figure out how to even use them. I'm pretty unfamiliar with IDispatch, once again documentation is difficult to find, and what's there looks very confusing. Some places say to just assign the IDispatch property to an OleVariant and then I can access the properties directly with dot notation, but that doesn't seem to be working either for me, so maybe I'm doing it wrong.

Does anyone have any knowledge on how to pull out the response properties in a CoXMLHTTP60 call?

Comment: The `XMLHTTP` object has no JSON support.

Comment: JSON is a [very simple format](https://www.json.org) to parse manually, if you can't find a 3rd party parser that works in D6 (have you tried [lkjson](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lkjson/) or [uJSON](https://sourceforge.net/projects/is-webstart/) yet?).

Comment: @Olivier Ah, that makes sense. So in other words, looking at the other response properties to try to pull out the values is probably a lost cause. Looks like parsing the JSON is my only option, either manually or with a library.

Comment: Have you ever considered updating your Delphi to the current version? JSON is supported out of the box. There is Delphi Community Edition which you can use for free (Conditions applies for business) see https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/starter/free-download.

Comment: @fpiette We actually updated our product to the current version of Delphi a while ago, but unfortunately we still have a number of users that refuse to leave our legacy version that's still compiled with Delphi 6, so we have to do a small amount of support for this product to keep these customers happy. We updated our server to Windows Server 2019 and it broke compatibility with the old component we used for this, so I had to update our legacy product to connect to our web server for registration purposes another way, which is why I wrote the code above. Thanks!

Comment: @RemyLebeau In the end I solved this by using the code above to get the JSON response from the server in a string, then I wrote a small custom JSON parser to parse it out like you said. The parser is quite customized to the format I know the data is going to be in and not extensive enough for any other purposes, but since this is a legacy product I don't expect it to change much and it should be sufficient. Thanks everyone for your help and comments!

Comment: @dallin since you have access to a modern Delphi version, an alternative would be to write a DLL in that version that uses Delphi’s native [JSON framework](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/JSON) to parse the downloaded JSON string, and then you can use that DLL in your Delphi 6 project.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Whoa. That's brilliant. You just blew my mind! I can't tell you how many times I would have used that approach already if I had only thought of it earlier! Thank you!